# Contesting answer deletion

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

An answer of mine was deleted on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750728/how-to-assign-columns-of-data-to-variables?noredirect=1#comment63222550_37750728) question. I'm conflicted because I think I understand why my answer was deleted (I went on a bit long about why someone should install pandas instead of rolling it themselves), but at the same time, my answer helped the user, was accepted, upvoted, and gave general advice that would be applicable to anyone facing a similar problem.

There was no reason given for the deletion, and it's not like I'm a brand new user stepping out for my first time. I don't see how it would be for any of the reasons listed in the help center.

Comment: I don't know the context but a comment would appear to have been warranted *at the very least*.

Comment: Not sure what happened there - I've undeleted the answer - sorry about that.

Comment: It was flagged as 'not an answer'. I saw the question; saw the first paragraph of the answer; and it looked like more of an ad than an answer; so I nuked it. A more careful examination shows that was incorrect. Sorry about that.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Oh, no worries, thanks a lot for being so receptive!

Comment: Note that question says " I'd prefer a solution without it{pandas}". You may  want to re-order your answer or clarify that you cover both options in first sentence/paragraph of your long answer.